# How to remove Hibernate debug statements from WildFly debug log

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am using WildFly log in debug mode and it shows a lot of unnecessary debug statements from Hibernate and I need to stop them.
This is what I have changed in my `standalone-full.xml`.

```
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate">
            <level name="INFO"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
</profile>
```

But it has no effect.

Please suggest me how to do that.

My console is full with such statements.

```
13:19:56,260 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] 
(DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Resolving associations for [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512575]
13:19:56,260 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Done materializing entity [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512575]
13:19:56,261 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Resolving associations for [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512576]
13:19:56,261 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Done materializing entity [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512576]
13:19:56,261 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Resolving associations for [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512577]
13:19:56,262 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Done materializing entity [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512577]
13:19:56,262 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) Resolving associations for [com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.ErrorTable#10512578]
```

I want to stop these debug logs and only show the one I have added in the application.

Comment: Please edit your question to share logging subsystem of your standalone-full.xml

Comment: @SevanNerse please check edited question

Comment: Do you see them if you change the console-handler to INFO? `/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=INFO)`

Comment: no it does not show it if i change it to INFO. @JamesR.Perkins

Comment: I'm not sure what it could be then. You've got the `org.hibernate` category set to `INFO`. Somewhere something must be overriding that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new logger entry:

```
<logger category="org.hibernate">
  <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

This way only `INFO` and above level messages will be logged.

Also, delete the logging level line from the `console-handler`.

Comment: @kirti Please, see my edited answer. You also have to delete the logging level from the console handler (remove `<level name="DEBUG"/>` line).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is not using [Per-deployment Logging](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging). If that's the case the logging subsystem configurations won't have any effect.

Comment: In a "Per-deployment Logging" the configuration file is in the META-INF directory, if it is an EAR deployment, or either the META-INF or WEB-INF/classes directories if it is in a WAR or JAR deployment.

The possible configuration files are: logging.properties, jboss-logging.properties, log4j.properties, log4j.xml, jboss-log4j.xml.

Observe that the DEBUG info was logged by the Quartz scheduler... so if you have more than one deployment, pay special attention to the deployment that is using the Quartz scheduler.